# Select Max two rows of each account SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table

```
ID     AGE     ACCNUM     NAME
--------------------------------
1      10      55409      Intro
2      6       55409      Chapter1
3      4       55409      Chapter2
4      3       69591      Intro
5      6       69591      Outro
6      0       40322      Intro
```

And I need a query that returns the two max age from each `ACCNUM`
in this case, records:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 6
```

I have tried too many queries but nothing works for me.

I tried this query

```
Select 
    T1.accnum, T1.age 
from 
    table1 as T1
inner join 
    (select 
         accnum, max(age) as max 
     from table1 
     group by accnum) as T2 on T1.accnum = T2.accnum 
                            and (T1.age = T2.max or T1.age = T2.max -1)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Use a `ROW_NUMBER` and `ORDER BY` `DESC` in your `OVER` clause.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Yatiac, which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL Ranking Functions: `Row_Number()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
  select id, age, accnum, name 
  from 
  (
     select id, age, accnum, name, ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By accnum order by age desc) as rn
     from yourtable
  ) a
  where a.rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select accnum
     , age
from ( select accnum
            , age
            , row_number() over(partition by accnum order by age desc) as r
       from table1 as T1) t where r < 3
```

Answer (score 1):

CODE:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT ID, AGE, ACCNUM, NAME,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCNUM ORDER BY AGE DESC) AS ROW_NUM
             FROM T1)
SELECT ID, AGE, ACCNUM, NAME
FROM CTE
WHERE ROW_NUM <= 2
```

Uses a common table expression to achieve the desired result.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/52d6e/2/0)